# Angular ionic app failes with optimization set to true on Android and ios

Tags: android, ios, angular

My Angular 15.2.9 with Ionic 6.20.1 app is running perfect on ios and Android, in dev environment where no production optimizations are defined.

However, in testing configuration, where the **optimizations parameter in the angular.json file is set to true** - the app launches with a white screen (or endless splash screen), throwing this error and warnings:

```
TypeError: ke.auth is not a function
    at main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js:1:441548
    at i.invoke (polyfills.c6003a5bf9d4f072.js:1:34256)
    at T.run (polyfills.c6003a5bf9d4f072.js:1:29603)
    at Gl.runOutsideAngular (main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js:1:1223629)
    at main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js:1:441523
    at Ie (main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js:1:451361)
    at ue (main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js:1:441461)
    at new Kt (main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js:1:446807)
    at Kt.ɵfac [as factory] (main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js:1:449148)
    at Op.hydrate (main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js:1:1168637)

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost/polyfills.c6003a5bf9d4f072.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost/main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost/runtime.89822dc9d1d9571d.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost/styles.d1b4daa0e98f64c2.css.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Looking in the generated www files, these files are found, and they are correctly refereced to in the adjacent index.html file:

```
<script src="runtime.89822dc9d1d9571d.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.c6003a5bf9d4f072.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js" type="module"></script>
```

In the minimized file *main.9acac4ae4b92c059.js* I did find the section where this *ke.auth* is called, it looks like it is related to the Firebase authentication section, that looks like this in my original code:

```
import {
  ActionPerformed,
  PushNotifications,
  PushNotificationSchema,
  Token,
} from "@capacitor/push-notifications";

...

initPush() {
    if (Capacitor.getPlatform() !== "web") {
      this.registerPush();
    } else {
      this.onFCMTokenChanged.next("web-platform");
    }
  }

  private registerPush() {
    PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then((permission) => {
      if (permission.receive === "granted") {
        console.log('FireBase Permission granted');

        PushNotifications.register();
      } else {            
        console.log('FireBase NO permissions granted');
      }
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener("registration", (token: Token) => {
      if (token && !this.tokenProcessed) {
        this.tokenProcessed = true;
        console.log('My token: ' + JSON.stringify(token));
        this.onFCMTokenChanged.next(token.value);

        setLocal("device-token", token.value);
      }
    });
```

The console Networking tab tells us the the only requests made were about 12 successful reqeusts for the favicon.png file - no other request is registered.

I am deploying the app directly from Android Studio / xcode to Android / iPhone devices connected directly via a USB cable to my dev machine. Same error is thrown on both platforms.

This is how the angular.json configuration looks like for the testing environment:

```
"configurations": {
            "testing": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "9mb"
                }
              ]
            },
```

Any ideas what is going on here?